# HTTP Unauthorized when using '"App Step"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

I have a workflow using "App Step" to get ID of group, get ID of permission level and assign permission for some user in items in a list.

App step already have full control permission and it running OK until 5 PM 17/03/2018, now all my application using "App Step" was die with message:

最後の要求を再試行しています。次の試行は 1 分以内に行われます。最後の要求の詳細: https://....sharepoint.com/sites/........./_api/web/lists(guid'2981af22-4813-478d-899d-f5169a533ecf')/Items(235)?%24select=ID%2CID に対する HTTP Unauthorized 関連付け ID: 5865523c-9ffd-5c57-91e4-cdfaa8165731 インスタンス ID: 5656746b-ce5a-4926-a5ed-c8694af0c89b 
今すぐ再試行する

May be Microsoft update any feature? I can't find them.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce in another SharePoint site collection or tenant?

Comment: yes, i do but it same error.

Comment: I think you really need to check the permission of the app principal. There would have to be a change. From SPO service update, I just checked and nothing happened in the mentioned timeframe.

Comment: Please share more on Http trace via Fiddler if possible. Also share the Url. From here I don't know if you call to parent web or sub web.